# How to hide dynamically created html element with a dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically created html elements under a for loop in JavaScript, these dynamic elements also has a dynamic id, my question is how can I hide the dynamically created elelment with a dynamic id. Thank you.

This is my code so far. I want to target the dynamic id and hide it.

```
product_list += '<div class="plProductContainer hide" data-pids="' + a_data.products[i].pid + '" id="'+a_data.products[i].pid+'">';
```

It has a dynamic id.

Comment: you can use its index to hide specific element

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you will use classes instead of id, but for this example you could use something like this. hide the element using a class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(){
    $(".add-more").on("click", function(){
      var list  = $(".list");
      
      var random_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
      
      var child = document.createElement("li");
      var text  = document.createTextNode("Lorem Ipsum");
          child.setAttribute("id", random_id);
          child.appendChild(text);
      
      list.append(child);
    });
  });
  
  $(function(){
    $(".list").on("click", "li", function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      $("#" + id).addClass("hidden");
      
      console.log("This id: " + id + " is hidden");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
a{
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul{
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover{
  color: red;
}
li + li{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
li.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a class="add-more">Click me!</a>
</div>

<ul class="list">
  <li id="0">Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want to target the dynamic id, onload not on using event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById(a_data.products[i].pid).style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you are using jquery. Try something like this:

```
$(".plProductContainer.hide").hide();
```

or

```
var elementId = $(".plProductContainer.hide").attr("id");
$("#"+elementId).hide();
```

or
If your element is inside another element with id someId, then:

```
$("#"+someId).children()[i].hide(); //i is the loop counter that you have used to create element dynamically
```

or

```
$("#"+a_data.products[i].pid).hide(); //i is the loop counter that you have used to create element dynamically
```

It becomes easier if you already know the values of you loop counter i.e value of i, if you don't know that then you can also use selectors like nth child. Let me know if any of the above works, else I'll put up more selectors.